# How to automatically upload build on testflight?

Tags: ios, testflight

Currently I follow the below steps:
1 - Upload on build using Application Loader.
2 - Go to iTunesconnect and wait for the 'processing' of newly uploaded build to complete.
3 - After the processing is completed, go to TestFlight -> Internal Testing and the choose the new build and then click 'Save'.

After I hit 'Save' all my testers get an mail. What I want to know is can I avoid step 2 and 3 ? Today one of my colleagues, did the 1st step and said he was done uploading the build to testflight. When I questioned him what about step 2 and 3, he said that's not required and that is how it is configured, not giving an explanation. Can someone tell me how it's done ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope this might help you
https://medium.com/@hlung/automating-ios-app-testflight-deployment-with-jenkins-7122cb741309#.nhkenaf60

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2015/12/15/Automating-Testflight-Deploys/

Answer (score 2):

You can also use https://www.bitrise.io/ or the offline bitrise CLI https://www.bitrise.io/cli , depending where you want to run this process.
There are two Bitrise build Steps which can be used for this, a Shenzhen based one, and a (fastlane) `deliver` based one (http://www.bitrise.io/integrations - search for `itunes`)

Answer (score 1):

In order to automate the **Testflight Build deployment**.
You can either use **Jenkins** or **Fastlane**.

In detail tutorials are provided in the following links

https://medium.com/@hlung/automating-ios-app-testflight-deployment-with-jenkins-7122cb741309#.nhkenaf60

http://artsy.github.io/blog/2015/12/15/Automating-Testflight-Deploys/

Answer (score 1):

Use fastlane. It is very easy to setup and use. Follow these steps if you want to use it.

1. Launch terminal.
2. Navigate to your project directory.
3. Enter command `sudo gem install fastlane`. This will install fastlane.
4. Then run `fastlane init`. This will create *Fastfile* in the folder fastlane.
5. Open Fastfile in the text editor.
6. In the Fastfile search "***lane :beta do***".
7. Write  these line under  "***lane :beta do***".

`increment_build_number
gym(scheme: "myScheme”)
pilot`

8. Open Appfile (exists in same folder as Fastfile) in the text editor.
9. Add these lines in Appfile.

`app_identifier "com.company.app" # The bundle identifier of your app
apple_id "abc@gmail.io" # Your Apple email address
team_id "XXXXXXXXXX"  # Developer Portal Team ID`

10. After that, in the terminal run command `fastlane beta`.

It will start building and then uploading build to the Testflight. All your internal testers will be automatically notified once the build processing is done.

Now you just have to run the command `fastlane beta` next time to upload the build to the testflight.